# Как деобфусцировать/расшифровать этот lua код?

Tags: lua

Нужна часть кода, но она защищена. Хотелось бы узнать, что это за тип "обфускации/шифрования" и как его можно "деобфусцировать/расшифровать"?
Я могу использовать не верные слова, не бейте.

Часть кода:
1b4c 4a01 0232 0001 0800 0101 0927 0100
0034 0200 0010 0300 003e 0202 0444 0501
8014 0100 0142 0503 024e 05fd 7f48 0102
000a 7061 6972 7302 4900 0209 0101 000d
2702 0100 2b03 0000 1004 0000 3e03 0202
2704 0100 4902 0680 3606 0500 1007 0600
3706 0006 1008 0100 3e06 0301 4b02 fa7f
4700 0100 00c0 1073 6574 5f76 6973 6962
6c65 8d03 0000 0308 0106 5b2b 0000 0010
0100 0037 0000 003e 0002 0209 0000 0054
0005 802b 0001 002b 0102 0029 0202 003e
0003 0154 0004 802b 0001 002b 0102 0029
0201 003e 0003 012b 0000 0010 0100 0037
0000 003e 0002 0209 0001 0054 0005 802b
0001 002b 0103 0029 0202 003e 0003 0154
0004 802b 0001 002b 0103 0029 0201 003e
0003 012b 0000 0010 0100 0037 0000 003e
0002 0209 0002 0054 0005 802b 0001 002b
0104 0029 0202 003e 0003 0154 0004 802b

Comment: Это байт-код LuaJIT.  Вам нужен декомпилятор LuaJIT.